# Core Data, storing html in string type

Tags: core-data

How much info will String data type allow me to store? I am looking to store full html text. Is this possible/recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreData string will hold a lot. It should only be limited by the underlying implementation, if at all. I've stored full web pages in core data before with no issues at all.

If I had more time I'd write a little loop that incrementally grew a string in core data to see if a limit is ever reached, and if so where that limit is (maybe I will later).